# Движение контента мышкой

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как двигать контент мышкой?
Как это называется и как осуществить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Щепотку функций. Перемещение по оси X добавить по вкусу

```js
function grab(g) {
  g.onmousemove = function(e) {
    g.scrollTop += -e.movementY;
    return false;
  }
  
  g.onmouseleave = function() { g.onmousemove = null; }
  g.onmouseup = function() { g.onmousemove = null; }
}
```

```css
div {
  cursor: grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  
  height: 256px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

div:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
}
```

```html
<div onmousedown='grab(this)'>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
  content<br>
</div>
```

Comment: На сайте [hotdot.pro](http://hotdot.pro) это работает через `work.js`, скрипт минифицирован, но по классу `grab` и `grabbing` можно найти

Answer (score 3):

На сайте что ты привел как пример используется [dragscroll](https://github.com/asvd/dragscroll)

> Dragscroll is a micro JavaScript library (838 bytes minified) which
>   enables scrolling via holding the mouse button ("drag and drop" or
>   "click and hold" style, online demo). It has no dependencies and is
>   written in vanilla JavaScript (which means it works anywhere).

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите плагины drag drop. 
Происходит обычный захват и перетаскивание контента, а точнее `body>.container`.